# PWA not working with Angular Pre Rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I' working with Angular 10 Universal project.

When I run below command

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run PROJECT:server:production && node dist/PROJECT/server/main.js",
```

I could see the service-workers getting registed.

So now If I run the below command, I could see all the pages getting rendered but `ngsw` files are not getting generated and in browser also service workers are not registed.

```
"prerender": "ng run PROJECT:prerender"
```

What I'm going wrong here ? Please guide

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, scope: './', registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })
```

inside `app.module.ts`